# Como comprobar conexión a internet en python3

Tags: python-3.x, wifi

La idea general es comprobar si el dispositivo está conectado a la wifi. Lo he intentado con socket y excepciones, pero no de resultado.

```
try:
    testConn.connect(('https://www.google.com', 80))
    testConn.close()
    break
except:
    testConn.close()
```

Lo tengo metido en un bucle que se costa cuando hay wifi. A ser posible me gustarí no depender de pip aun que si es necesario lo puedo utilizar.

Answer (score 2):

La forma más fácil de comprobar si tienes conexión es con el paquete *requests*.

```py
import requests
try:
    request = requests.get("www.google.com", timeout=5)
except (requests.ConnectionError, requests.Timeout):
    print("Sin conexión a internet.")
else:
    print("Con conexión a internet.")
```

Como no quieres usar librerías externas, puedes usar este código para comprobar si tienes conexión mediante sockets.

```py
import socket
s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.settimeout(5)
try:
    s.connect(("www.google.com", 80))
except (socket.gaierror, socket.timeout):
    print("Sin conexión a internet")
else:
    print("Con conexión a internet")
    s.close()
```